# Tool to ask adressbook for pgp keys

Tags: thunderbird, pgp, enigmail

I would like to know if somebody knows a tool, where i can query my whole adress book in Thunderbird or Gmail, to ask, if there are PGP keys for somebody there. So i can just use the PGP key of People there.
Or can I do this with Gnupg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Thunderbird 38.3 and Enigmail 1.8:

1. Settings
2. Enigmail
3. Key Management
4. Keyserver
5. Find keys for all contacts
6. Select all found keys
7. OK

Answer (score 2):

I guess that feature lacks in your version of [enigmail](https://enigmail.net/), the GnuPG client for Thunderbird.
Therefore I suggest you export your contacts into a "comma separated" formatted file (thunderbird > addressbook > Tools > Export) and then pipe it through gpg in the command line. e.g.:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","};{print "gpg --search-keys --keyserver pgp.mit.edu " $5}' exported-file.csv | sh
```

*(Whereas FS="," defines the "field separator" and $5 the fifth field, which is the field containing the e-mail address of the respective user.)*

Otherwise try to upgrade your [Enigmail](https://enigmail.net/) add-on, as v1.6 seems to support that function:

> New function to search for the OpenPGP keys of all Address Book entries on a keyserver.

In version 1.6 you can find the option in Thunderbird > OpenPGP > Keyserver > "Find keys for all contacts".

Check here: [Source](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/enigmail/) (Section "Version Information")

Comment: i think you forgot keymanagement after OpenPGP. > Keymanagement > Keyserver

Comment: Well, yes, one would have to configure a keyserver when requesting the gpg keys for the addressbook in thunderbird, as well as in the command line. - I will add that for you ;)